# In unity, making a navmesh for a tiny planet?

Tags: unity, navmesh

I'm trying to build a scene in a small planet, and baking will always give me the result on the half top of the planet. But what I want is to create a navmesh all around the small planet.

I am wondering if there is a way to convert a mesh that I well built in blender, to be a navmesh in Unity. That means using the mesh totally without baking. Or, if there is some other ways to create navmesh for my poor planet.

Comment: Unity's navmesh is difficult for this purpose. The mesh is highly simplified. Wrapping it around a round object would require many verticies, which sorta defeats the point of the nav mesh. A planet can be treated like a flat surface for the purposes of navigation, since we navigate it the same way as a flat world. If you want to use unity's built in and not make your own, you can do something crazy. Have a flattened version of your level that mimics the round one. Navigate on that. This is an awful solution, i really would recommend finding another nav system.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a thread on doing just what you're asking about: https://forum.unity.com/threads/new-navmesh-how-to-create-rotated-localnavmeshbuilder-solved.476489/

This might require you to break your planet into pieces based on angle thresholds and link them together. You could possibly get away with 3 - one for the north pole, one for south, and one for equatorial. You could also hide separate meshes and only display the single planet mesh and the NavMesh will still be valid.

Take a look at the Unity NavMesh Extensions here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents

I think those extensions are required for the classes they are talking about and to link nav meshes together. I've used them to generate meshes at runtime in the past.

Edit to enumerate what is in the Unity thread from the Unity employee adriant:

> Hi! You will need to change the code to set the rotation of the NavMeshData object before building the NavMesh. This means adding something like this

```
m_NavMesh.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(41, Vector3.forward);
```

> any time before NavMeshBuilder.UpdateNavMeshDataAsync(...) or NavMeshBuilder.UpdateNavMeshData(...) are called.

> The NavMeshSurface takes the rotation from its game object when the NavMesh >gets built with this call

```
    var data = NavMeshBuilder.BuildNavMeshData(GetBuildSettings(), sources, sourcesBounds, transform.position, transform.rotation);
```

> This effectively creates a NavMeshData object, sets its position and >up->vector orientation and then calls UpdateNavMeshData(...).
>
> Please see also the documentation pages for NavMeshData and >NavMeshBuilder.BuildNavMeshData .
>
> When the NavMeshData needs to be aligned with the originating geometry then it has to be added to the NavMesh system with the same position & rotation with which it was built. Try this in your code:

```
if (m_NavMesh.rotation != transform.rotation)
    {
        m_NavMesh.rotation = transform.rotation; // I've added this line
        m_Instance.Remove();
        m_Instance = NavMesh.AddNavMeshData(m_NavMesh, m_NavMesh.position, m_NavMesh.rotation);
    }
```

> You get freedom for where to place your NavMesh data in the world. Multiple instances of the same NavMeshData can be used by the NavMesh
> system in various locations and with whichever orientation you need.
> As a side note, changing the position or rotation of the NavMeshData
> will trigger a full build of that nav mesh, unlike just
> moving/changing the bounds which doesn't recompute the nav mesh in
> unchanged areas.
>
> Please keep in mind though that the bounds passed to
> UpdateNavMeshData() are local to m_NavMesh. This means that for the
> LocalNavMeshBuilder class at least the bounds' center needs to be
> adjusted. Try adding this in QuantizedBounds():

```
if (m_NavMesh)
    {
        var nmMatrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(m_NavMesh.position, m_NavMesh.rotation, Vector3.one);
        center = nmMatrix.inverse.MultiplyPoint(center);   // from world to local space
    }
```

> And make sure to adjust the gizmos' transform accordingly in OnDrawGizmosSelected() with:

```
Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(m_NavMesh.position, m_NavMesh.rotation, Vector3.one);
```